# Cyclotomic polynomial,

Tags: polynomials, roots-of-unity

> Show that $\displaystyle X^n-1=\prod_{d\mid n}\Phi_d(X)$.

We have that $$\Phi_n(X)=\prod_{\underset{\gcd(i,n)=1}{1\leq i\leq n}}(X-\zeta_n^i)$$
where $\zeta_n=e^{\frac{2i\pi}{n}}$ therefore, we have to show that
$$X^n-1=\prod_{d\mid n}\prod_{\underset{\gcd(i,d)=1}{1\leq i\leq d}}(X-\zeta_d^i).$$

My first idea is to show that both has same roots and that all their roots are distinct. For the unicity of the roots of $X^n-1$ it's obvious. It's ovbious to that all roots of $\Phi_d(X)$. But how can I show that they have the same roots and that the roots of $$\prod_{d\mid n}\Phi_d(X)$$
are distinct ?

Comment: It's only a mad idea, but trying by induction on $n$ and using the rule "$(f,f')\neq 1 \Leftrightarrow f\; has \; multiple \;factors$" doesn't work?

Comment: Not easy to derivate all these product no ?

Comment: By definition, the roots of $\Phi_n$ are exactly the $\zeta_n^i$ with $gcd(i,n) = 1.$ For such an $i,$ we have $(\zeta_n^i)^m = 1$ iff $n|m.$ In other words, the roots of $\Phi_n$ are exactly the _primitive_ $n$-th roots of unity. Are you aware of this?

Answer (score 0):

$$X^n-1=\prod_{d\mid n}\prod_{\underset{\gcd(i,d)=1}{1\leq i\leq d}}(X-\zeta_d^i).$$

You need to show that

$$\prod_{\underset{\gcd(i,d)=1}{1\leq i\leq d}}(X-\zeta_d^i)=\Phi_d(X)$$

> Note $f(x)=X^n-1$ is separable or has distinct roots. (A polynomial over a field of characteristic $0$ is separable if $f'\ne 0$). Also $\Phi_d(X)|f(x)$ and thus it is also separable.

Consider the RHS, its roots are the primitive $d^{th}$ roots of unity i.e. if $\zeta$ is a root then $|\zeta|=d$. Clearly LHS is satisfied by all such $\zeta$'s since the LHS is satisfied by all the $n^{th}$ roots of order $d$ (Since, $|\zeta_d^i|=d$)  and $RHS|LHS$

Also degree of LHS and RHS is same (thus, the $\phi(d)$ **distinct** roots of $\Phi_d(X)$ satisfy LHS) and both are monic and thus we can conclude that LHS=RHS and your claim is proved.

Comment: I don't understand: "you need to prove that $\prod_{\underset{\gcd(i,d)=1}{1\leq i\leq d}}(X-\zeta_d^i)=\Phi_d(X)$" because this is by definition.

Comment: But if it is already a well known fact, then you directly get the result, where is the problem?

Comment: In the first line of the answer, you are using the "cyclicity"of the $n^{th}$ roots and you are kind of "partitioning" the roots by their orders. (You'd get a root of order $d$ for each $d|n$ since the roots form a cyclic group). Now if you show what I've done above, I think it would suffice, though I am waiting for a confirmation as I am new to field theory.